# No bean matching found when using both XML and annotation based configuration

Tags: xml, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I have an old application which uses a lot of XML based configuration for its dependencies and we are trying to convert most of it into annotation based configuration. However it is not possible to completely remove it in one go so I want to keep both the type of configurations.

There are a few dependencies in the XML which have already been initialized in the annotation context and I need them to be in the same context for things to work.

//This is just pseudo code to explain my question

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath*:com/cric/ipl/parentApplicationContext.xml")
@ComponentScan("classpath*:com/cric")
public class MySpringConfiguration{

@Bean("SportsBean")
public SportsBean sportsBean (){
   return new SportsBean();
}

}
```

Inside the `parentApplicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="someOtherBean" class="com.fifa.football.russia.SomeOtherBean">
   <property name="first" ref="SportsBean">
</beans>
```

When I initialize the xml config file it says "No matching bean found for SportsBean" even though I have initialized it in `MySpringConfiguration` class. So I need that beans of XML config be able to use beans initialized in Annotation Config.

In `main` method, this is how I initialized `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ();
ctx.register(MySpringConfiguration.class);
```

Can some one help me on this problem? I hope I have been able to explain the question for others to answer. Feel free to tell me if my problem is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: I have given name as @Bean("SportsBean"). It could be a typo here but the question is how can I make use of both the context together.

Comment: Missed that, removed the comment. Although I would recommend sticking with the defaults. In theory it should work as everything is merged into 1 large context and then dependencies are resolved. Is your `SportsBean` als an `@Component`? Also your `@ComponentScan` is also wrong it takes a package not a path pattern `@CompontScan("com.cric")` is the correct one. Also please add the `SportsBean` and `SomeOtherBean` to see the definitions. And please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: also the fact that you use pseudo code basically makes it that this doesn't show the actual problem as it is a dumbed down version. Mixing XML and Java works perfectly well (used it on many occasions) so not showing actual code but a modified version will actually make things harder to debug.

Comment: SportsBean is not a component. And yes I have modified @ComponentScan with java package convention. Unfortunately I can't put the real code here. Is it possible that when the beans in the XML are getting initialised it looks up into the annotation context to see if exists there? Any usage of a Bean Pre processor here?

Comment: There is only 1 context all the beans are part of the same context. Also you should be doing a `ctx.refresh` after the `ctx.register`. As stated your code is a dumbed down version and doesn't show the complete picture. Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the issue. The code here should work as is (and I have used such a setup many times before).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has been solved, but just by looking at it, it seem you forgot to add the *name* property to the *@Bean* annotation. Also, the spring bean naming convention is that bean names start with a lowercase letter and are camel-cased.

```
   @Bean(name = "sportsBean")
   public SportsBean sportsBean (){
    return new SportsBean();
   }
```

Also, since the name of the bean is the same as the same of the method that creates the bean, you can alternatively omit explicitly naming the bean because by default Spring names the bean the same as the method that is used to create the bean

```
public SportsBean sportsBean (){
 return new SportsBean();
}
```